# What is the name of Sardinian-Emilia Romagna cuisine adding wine to the end of cheese broth

Tags: wine, broth, romanian-cuisine

Following [this](https://youtu.be/ueJr_rlzLa0?t=1524) video, what is the name of the Sardinian-Emilia Romagna cuisine that adds wine at the end of the cheese broth, as advised by Edoardo Celadon?

Comment: Questions about health are specifically off-topic. Asking about the name is fine.

Comment: All of that information is explicitly contained in the video.  What are you looking to find out, that's not in the video?

Comment: Can you tell me what is the name of the cuisine that adds wine at the end of the cheese broth? and a background about it?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “name of the cuisine”. Names like, “Italian cuisine” or “vegetarian cuisine”?

Comment: @SneftelI, I asked specifically about the name of the cuisine that shown in the attached above video that adds wines at the end of cheese broth.

Comment: @avi your question makes little sense. You seem, from your comments, to be asking for the name of the fish, not the cuisine (which means more like the cooking culture of a region or group of people)

Comment: Avi, I'm with Sneftel here. I can't understand what "the name of the cuisine in the video" means. Especially since there was an answer, and you said this is not what you mean.

Comment: For future note, Avi meant "dish", not "cuisine".  Not advocating for reopening though.

Answer (score 2):

[Emilia-Romagna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emilia-Romagna) is a province in the North of Italy, and includes the two cities of Bologna and Parma.  As such, [Emilia-Romagna's food](https://www.italianbellavita.com/2012/10/the-traditional-food-of-emiliaromagna/) is definitional for "Northern Italian" cuisine.

The cuisine includes many foods which are internationally famous, including:

- Prosciutto
- Parmigiano Reggiano
- Tortellini
- Balsamic Vinegar
- Sangiovese wine

Sardinia is a separate part of Italy, an island to the west, and has its own cuisine.

Comment: I asked specifically about the name of the cuisine that shown in the attached above video that adds wines at the end of cheese broth.

Comment: @Avi  The name of the cuisine is “northern Italian cuisine”. If the answer you’re looking for is not “northern Italian cuisine” then you need to figure out the words for the actual question you wanted to ask. (Perhaps try a different translation dictionary.)

Comment: @Sheftel, in the video he mentioned something like Surbeer. Please watch the attached video.

Comment: @Avi, to reiterate what's been said already, what you're asking for isn't what you want.  There's (according to the video) a tradition *within the cuisine of Emilia Romagna*, and that's what you'd like to know about - either that or the name of a specific dish.

Comment: @Avi I now took a look at the video. It seems that the guy using the word is a public figure. Maybe you can ask him directly on a social media channel.

Comment: Thanks @rumtscho!
I asked in other forum and this is part of the answer I got. Thanks to Gabriele Calvillo: Sorbir is a Lombardy way to call the broth, used in the Cremona and Mantua Provinces, pretty near to Emilia Romagna and where the Po river do as the boundary between the two regions.
It means , in Lumbard dialct, just “to sip”.
Sorbir d’Agnoli is quite typical of Mantua, and it is a RICH soup, made by Agnoli ( a king of meat ravioli, cooked in a made of hen and beef broth.

Comment: @Avi the word you wanted was "dish", not "cuisine".  A "cuisine" is a whole body of food for a region.